# text_multifile_backend how to set rool file size

Tags: c++, boost

I have big problem with configuration boost::log. 
I need to set max log file size. I tried to do this like that:

```
// Create a text file sink
    typedef boost::log::sinks::synchronous_sink< boost::log::sinks::text_multifile_backend > file_sink;

    // set log file size
    boost::shared_ptr< boost::log::sinks::text_file_backend > backend =
        boost::make_shared< boost::log::sinks::text_file_backend >(
            boost::log::keywords::rotation_size = 1 * 1024 * 1024
        );

    boost::shared_ptr< file_sink > sink(new file_sink(backend));

    // Set up how the file names will be generated
    sink->locked_backend()->set_file_name_composer(boost::log::sinks::file::as_file_name_composer(
    boost::log::expressions::stream << "logs/" << boost::log::expressions::attr< std::string >("logger_name") << ".log"));
```

But it not even compile :/.

> Error 1   error C2664:
>   'boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_multifile_backend::text_multifile_backend(const
>   boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_multifile_backend &)' : cannot
>   convert parameter 1 from 'const boost::shared_ptr' to 'const
>   boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_multifile_backend
>   &'    ....................\boost_1_54_0\boost\smart_ptr\make_shared_object.hpp    259

How to configure log file size?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible using text_multifile_backend, read here: [Boost.Log Text multi-file backend](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sink_backends.html#log.detailed.sink_backends.text_multifile)

> The multi-file backend has no knowledge of whether a particular file is going to be used or not. That is, if a log record has been written into file A, the library cannot tell whether there will be more records that fit into the file A or not. This makes it impossible to implement file rotation and removing unused files to free space on the file system. The user will have to implement such functionality himself.

You could try writing your own Boost.Log Sink which can be used with Boost.Log library and implement such functionality there: [Boost.Log Writing your own sink](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/extension.html#log.extension.sinks).

Comment: So i can't have many log files and use roll files without writing new sink?

Comment: I believe so. Current Boost.Log API (1.54.0) does not allow that. You could always just create multiple rotating sinks and point them to different log files. But you can't use text_multifile_backend for that.

Comment: Do you think could i use some other lib? Log4cpp will support this? I need 3 loggers which log to other files, log levels and file roller.

Comment: I think to write my own log lib :). It could be easier :)

Comment: But boost log is complicated. I spent one day to configure log to many files. I think it will be quicker to write something new. Boost log look also to be slow. I prepare while(true){loging} and it took some time to fill log file to 1MB :/

Comment: I'm in the same boat; did you end up using some other library?